# php code for enter data when first day of month

Tags: php

i have function for enter data in php for last date of month but how can i change in to first day of month.this is code for last day of month.

```
<?php 
$a_date= date("Y-m-d");
$last_date= date("Y-m-t", strtotime($a_date)); 
if($a_date==$last_date){ }else{ } 
?>
```

Comment: i suggested code fopr first day of month <?php
$a_date= date("Y-m-d");

 $first_date= date("Y-m-t", strtotime($a_date));
if($a_date==$first_date){

//run the update query for month avg

}

else{
//noting to  do

}
?

Comment: @DainisAbols here i have run code when las day of month but i want that function run  in to first day of month . please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First day of the month:
`date('Y-m-01');`

Last day of the month:
`date('Y-m-t');`

Answer (score 1):

```
$a_date= date("j");
$last_date= date("t");
if($a_date==$last_date){ 
    // Last day of the month.
} elseif (date("j") == 1 {
    // First day of the month.
} else {
    // None of the above apply.
}
```